# Mediawiki page for users to leave anonymous comments?

Tags: mediawiki

It seems really simple...but i'll be damned if i can find an extension that does this!!

I'm using Mediawiki 1.18 and all i really want it a page that links from the main homepage that acts as a blank page for ANYONE on my wiki to be able to post their ideas anonyously WITHOUT their names being shown on their posts! I only want this feature on one page of my wiki. So to conclude i just want to be able to set up 1 page that has anonymous posting enabled.

Any ideas? (no pun intended!)

Comment: I assume you mean that the usernames / IP addresses should not show up in the edit history of that page? That (and recent changes) is only place where MediaWiki automatically records them.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to write a [PageContentSave](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/PageContentSave) hook that attributes all edits to a particular page to a non-existent user, by changing the `$user` paramater which is passed in by reference, something like this:

```php
function anonymizeSandboxEdits( &$wikiPage, &$user, &$content, &$summary,
                                $isMinor, $isWatch, $section ) {
    $title = $wikiPage->getTitle();
    if ( $title->getNamespace() == NS_PROJECT && $title->getText() == 'Sandbox' ) {
        $user = User::newFromName( 'Anonymous' );
    }
    return true;  // keep running other hooks
}

$wgHooks['PageContentSave'][] = 'anonymizeSandboxEdits';
$wgReservedUsernames[] = 'Anonymous';
```

Adding this code to your LocalSettings.php should cause all edits to the page "Project:Sandbox" (where "Project:" is your project namespace name) to be attributed to the non-existent user "Anonymous".

Note that the PageContentSave hook was introduced very recently, in MediaWiki 1.21.  Older MediaWiki versions have a mostly equivalent hook named [ArticleSave](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ArticleSave), which takes essentially the same parameters and does essentially the same thing.  If you're still running an older version of MediaWiki, just replace `'PageContentSave`' above with `'ArticleSave'` and you should be fine.

The ArticleSave hook has been deprecated in MW 1.21, but is still retained for backward compatibility, so it should keep working even when you do upgrade.  However, I should note that there's no guarantee than something else won't break this trick in future MediaWiki versions: while replacing the `$user` object in that hook *seems* to work nicely for reattributing edits, that particular use case is not really documented as being explicitly supported.  The possibility exists that future changes to the MediaWiki code might break it more or less subtly.

---

Ps. I tried this on my own wiki (still running MW 1.20, so using the ArticleSave version), and it seems to work OK.  One somewhat curious side effect is that, if you try to sign the page with `~~~~`, it will show your real username in preview but will replace it with "Anonymous" when you actually save the page.  It might be possible to work around this, but it would require (also) using some other hook that actually gets run on preview.

Comment: Thats correct. I dont want any of the users to be able to tell whose written what on ONLY this page. I've added the code that you mentioned to the localsettings.php and changed the pagecontentsave to 'ArticleSave' and the wiki is operating fine apart from the fact i cant find the 'Project:Sandbox' page to test it! Do i now need to go in and create\edit this page? what variables would you recommend that i replace for it to say FREESPEECH as oposed to Project:Sandbox and how easy is it to get it to show in the navigation pane on the left hand side? any info would be legendary!

Comment: Yes, you need to create the page.  If you want the name of the page to be "FREESPEECH", then you'd replace the `if` condition with `if ( $title->getNamespace() == NS_MAIN && $title->getText() == 'FREESPEECH' )`. ([You can find a list of the `NS_` constants here.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace_constants)) As for adding it to the sidebar, you need to edit MediaWiki:Sidebar on your wiki; [see instructions here.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar)

Comment: Added the following code: `function anonymizeSandboxEdits( &$wikiPage, &$user, &$content, &$summary,
                                $isMinor, $isWatch, $section ) {
    $title = $wikiPage->getTitle();
    if ( $title->getNamespace() == NS_PROJECT && $title->getText() == 'FREESPEECH' ) {
        $user = User::newFromName( 'Anonymous' );
    }
    return true;  // keep running other hooks
}

$wgHooks['ArticleSave'][] = 'anonymizeSandboxEdits';
$wgReservedUsernames[] = 'Anonymous';`
but the version history still shows my name :(

Comment: Did you try it on "Project:FREESPEECH" or just "FREESPEECH"? Your code still has `NS_PROJECT` in it.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Is there an easy way for that page to simply blog in someway (comments only?) So that everytime someone posts it becomes a seperate post? like leaving comments on youtube etc...

Comment: You could _try_ combining it with [LiquidThreads](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LiquidThreads) or some other [discussion extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Discussion_and_forum_extensions), but I've no idea how they'd interact. It might work or it might not, depending on exactly how the extension is implemented; you could just try it and see. (Ps. Don't forget to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it works for you.)